# BigQuery Streaming with C# Client Library

Tags: google-bigquery

I've an Oracle table that needed to migrate to BigQuery. I wrote a simple console application with C# and started to streaming inserts. But sometimes aplication throws an error which is below. and my code is pretty simple that which is also below. Are there anyone have an idea what may cause this error? Thanks in advance.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred whi
        le sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
        was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the se
        rver. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connect
        ion: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.
        Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the r
        emote host
        at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.TlsStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
        ification(Task task)
        at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteUnparsedAsync>d__33.Mo
        veNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
        at Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClientImpl.InsertRows(TableReference tabl
        eReference, IEnumerable`1 rows, InsertOptions options)
        at Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClient.InsertRows(String datasetId, Strin
        g tableId, BigQueryInsertRow[] rows)
        at BigQueryStreamer.Program.UploadJsonStreamingSync(String datasetId, String
        tableId, BigQueryClient client, BigQueryInsertRow[] _rows) in C:\Projects\BigQue
        ryStreamer\BigQueryStreamer\Program.cs:line 330
        at BigQueryStreamer.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\BigQueryStream
        er\BigQueryStreamer\Program.cs:line 185
```

my code block is:

```
List<BigQueryInsertRow> _list = new List<BigQueryInsertRow>();
        while (oracleReader.Read())
            {
                BigQueryInsertRow bigQueryInsertRow = new BigQueryInsertRow();
                Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                for (int ordinal = 0; ordinal < oracleReader.FieldCount; ++ordinal)
                {
                    typeof(Decimal).ToString();
                    string str = oracleReader.GetValue(ordinal).GetType().ToString();
                    object obj = (str == "System.Decimal" || str== "System.Double" || str == "System.Float") ? 
                        (object)double.Parse(oracleReader.GetValue(ordinal).ToString()) :
                        (str == "System.DBNull" ? (object)null : oracleReader.GetValue(ordinal));
                    dictionary.Add(oracleReader.GetName(ordinal), obj);
                }
                bigQueryInsertRow.Add(dictionary);
                _list.Add(bigQueryInsertRow);

            }

            List<BigQueryInsertRow> _SendList = new List<BigQueryInsertRow>();

            //To Stream in 1000 rows at a time, I set _batcSize to 1000 in application configuration
            for (int i = 0; i < _list.Count; i++)
            {
                _SendList.Add(_list[i]);
                if (_SendList.Count == _batchSize)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
                    UploadJsonStreamingSync(_datasetid, _target, _client, _SendList.ToArray());
                    Console.WriteLine("Offset: " + ((ubound + 1) * _batchSize).ToString());
                    ubound++;
                    _SendList.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (_SendList.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
                UploadJsonStreamingSync(_datasetid, _target, _client, _SendList.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine("Offset: " + (_SendList.Count).ToString());
                ubound++;
                _SendList.Clear();
            }

            _list.Clear();
            _list = null;


        //Streaming Insert Function
        public static void UploadJsonStreamingSync(string datasetId, string tableId, BigQueryClient client, BigQueryInsertRow[] _rows)
        {
            client.InsertRows(datasetId, tableId, _rows);
        }
```

Comment: Is this a one off migrate of the table? If so, it would be easier to export it to CSV and bulk import from GCS. Socket timeouts can happen when using streaming because you are simply making network requests. You need to consider this when using the streaming API and bake some sort of exponential back and retry logic into your code.

Comment: It is a continues process. Once we migrate all the data from our RDBMS we will continue to sync it with BigQuery. I'm seeking a seamless integration and avoid creating extra CSV or Json files because those methods needs extra development effort and process to check.

Comment: You won't get seamless between Oracle & BigQuery. In fact, exporting to CSV or JSON is way easier (and more reliable), and less work than streaming. Like I said, if you go with streaming, you will get socket exceptions (i.e. network problems). You need to write logic to handle this. But, it's up to you what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

When facing infrequent socket exceptions/network issues as Graham pointed out you need to write logic to handle it.
There are libraries which you can use.
I used: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

*Polly is a .NET resilience and transient-fault-handling library that allows developers to express policies such as Retry, Circuit Breaker, Timeout, Bulkhead Isolation, and Fallback in a fluent and thread-safe manner.*